# DNS BIND 9.9 query only works for Fully Qualified Domain Name (FQDN) but not short name

Tags: dns, bind

I crashed into a problem trying to move my very old DNS BIND 9.5 to my new DNS BIND 9.9.
The issue is similar to this post:
[DNS query only works for Fully Qualified Domain Name (FQDN) but not short name](https://superuser.com/questions/735898/dns-query-only-works-for-fully-qualified-domain-name-fqdn-but-not-short-name)
But the problem is in Windows DNS client using short names.
When you query the old DNS with short names it resolves the FQDN. When you query the new DNS with short names, it fails. Both of them resolves well with the FQDN.
It is supposed that `nslookup` uses the domain suffix search.
The problem remains the same with Windows 8.1 and 10. I couldn't try this in other versions.

```
C:\Users\jsm> nslookup jsm 10.0.52.1
Servidor:  NSGal02.bancoxxx.com.ar
Address:  10.0.52.1
Nombre:  GAL115100.bancoxxx.com.ar
Address:  10.6.15.36
Aliases:  jsm.bancoxxx.com.ar

C:\Users\jsm> nslookup jsm 10.0.52.2
Servidor:  UnKnown
Address:  10.0.52.2

*** UnKnown no encuentra jsm: Server failed

C:\Users\jsm> nslookup jsm.bancoxxx.com.ar 10.0.52.2
Servidor:  UnKnown
Address:  10.0.52.2

Nombre:  GAL115100.bancoxxx.com.ar
Address:  10.6.15.36
Aliases:  jsm.bancoxxx.com.ar
```

Any clues?

Answer (score 0):

I guess there would be a problem in your TCP/IP properties of DNS suffix search order or the DNS table in your machine is corrupted. If so, entering the host's FQDN will allow DNS to locate the server. You may wish to try reediting the DNS table.

Comment: Hello. I reedited my resolver at my PC. I tried with another PC and the same happens. Made a diff between the old BIND and the new one and both configs are the same.
I put a lwres and it still fails.

It is the first time I see this behavior on a BIND. It is supposed the client searchs for the hostname adding each domain suffix but with BIND 9.9 the query fails. I will try with a wireshark to see what happens.

Comment: Ok I solved the problem. It happens that the Windows clients (joined my domain) do a first query to the ad domain (not the suffix) If the DNS response is NXDOMAIN then Windows clients continue to query the DNS with the suffix search list. My new DNS server didn't have the zone for that AD domain so it returned "server failed" and the Windows clients stop querying at that point. I added the zone for that AD domain (even without any RR) and it worked.